# Cannot implicitly convert type error when building query to populate viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I wanted to make a simple query to retrieve component data + language data for a specific article and then put that into a viewmodel.

The **ProductComponent** table is a child-table of **Product** and the relevant fields in it are the ComponentID and ProductId (foreign key, parentId), so I wanted to link ProductComponents to Product and ProductTranslations where I have all the language specific data, so I tried to make it all in one query to retrieve a list of components for a certain product.

Here is the query:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProductComponents> ListComponents(int productid, string language)
    {
        var query = (from c in context.ProductComponents

                     from ct in context.ProductTranslations
                     where ct.ProductId == c.ComponentId
                     where ct.ProductLanguage == language

                     from cp in context.Product
                     where cp.ProductId == c.ComponentId

                     where c.ProductId == productid

                     select new EnumComponents
                     {
                         ProductId = c.ComponentId,
                         Name = ct.ProductName,
                         SKU = cp.SKU
                     });

        return query;
    }
```

That gives this error, and highlighting the *return Query;* part as well:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Artikelhantering.Models.EnumComponents>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Artikelhantering.Models.ProductComponents>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Here is most of the data model, based on what I found googling and looking through Stack Overflow the relationships between tables might be the culprit, so I am including most of it.

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Article nr")]
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Product Category")]
        public int ProductCategoriesId { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Alternative Category")]
        public int? AdditionalCategoriesId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Show purchase button?")]
        public bool Purchase { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Show Product?")]
        public bool ShowProduct { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Picture name")]
        public string Picture { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Is reference product?")]
        public bool Reference { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Inprice")]
        public decimal inPrice { get; set; }    
        [DisplayName("Additional costs")]
        public decimal AddCost { get; set; } /
        [DisplayName("Weight in kg")]
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Volume in m^3")]
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Vat code, use 0")]
        public decimal VAT { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductTranslations> ProductTranslations { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductPrices> ProductPrices { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductComponents> ProductComponents { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductAccessories> ProductAccessories { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductCategories ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductCampaigns ProductCampaigns { get; set; }        
    }

    public class ProductTranslations 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductTranslationsId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; } // This one links to the Product class
        [DisplayName("Language Code")]
        public string ProductLanguage { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Product Name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [DisplayName("Meta Keywords")]
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        [DisplayName("Meta Description")]
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductComponents 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductComponentsId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductTranslations> ProductTranslations { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I define the relationships between the models like this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

                modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategories>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ProductCategoriesTranslations) // Categories has many Translations
                .WithRequired(y => y.ProductCategories)     // Translations require a category
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductCategoriesId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ProductPrices) // Product has many ProductPricings
                .WithRequired(y => y.Product)     // ProductPricing has required Product
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ProductTranslations) // Product has many ProductTranslations
                .WithRequired(y => y.Product)     // ProductTranslations has required Product
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ProductComponents) // Product has many ProductComponents
                .WithRequired(y => y.Product)     // ProductComponents has required Product
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ProductAccessories) // Product has many ProductAccessories
                .WithRequired(y => y.Product)     // ProductAccessories has required Product
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);

            }
```

I am guessing I need to define a proper relationship for ProductComponents to ProductTranslations and Product, but I am not quite sure how, I've tried various ways to create a relationship between ProductComponents -> ProductTranslations but without any success. Ofcourse the issue might well be somehing else.

Comment: Tried to rewrite the query like this, same error msg: `var query = (from c in context.ProductComponents
where c.ProductId == productid
select new EnumComponents
{
Name = c.ProductTranslations
            .Where(i => i.ProductLanguage == language)
            .Where(i => i.ProductId == c.ComponentId)
            .Select(i => i.ProductName)
            .Single(),
SKU = c.Product.SKU,
ProductId = c.ComponentId
});

return (query);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out on my own. Pretty simple and obvious error now that it finally clicked. The key was to rename **public IEnumerable<ListComponents>** to public **IEnumerable<EnumComponents>**

It seems logical in retrospect, I should be using the view model here and not the model, because that's what I am trying to populate after all, I can then call the model from inside the view model just fine.

```
public IEnumerable<EnumComponents> ListComponents(int productid, string language)
    {
        //return context.ProductComponents.Where(m => m.ProductId == productid);
        var query = (from c in context.ProductComponents
        where c.ProductId == productid
        select new EnumComponents
        {
        Name = c.ProductTranslations
                    .Where(i => i.ProductLanguage == language)
                    .Where(i => i.ProductId == c.ComponentId)
                    .Select(i => i.ProductName)
                    .Single(),
        SKU = c.Product.SKU,
        ProductId = c.ComponentId
        });

        return (query);
    }
```

Comment: This ofcourse lead to another problem with fields and relations, worked by changing the IList to IEnumberable in ProductComponents model. But now I get the following message instead: "The specified type member 'ProductTranslations' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." **This was solved by going back to the original query type**